# Mapping object signatures for required attributes

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to think of the best way to create a way to store the signatures of objects, in particular products.  There will be several types of products that will each have their own set of attributes and therefore different required attributes.

There will be different types of actions performed on the products, i.e validation etc.

At the moment the best i can think of is an associative array which has the attribute, whether its required or not and its data type but surely there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but can you use an actual object? (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php though that's probably a bit too much info at once)

Comment: im looking for a way to store the signature of an product so i can easily iterate over its properties i.e. price, order number, colour etc.  I need to also know which fields are required for inserting a new product etc.

Comment: Is the data stored in a database?

Comment: no it isnt.  I need to create a structure or a file to store the data

Comment: Ah. That's a pretty big question. Storing data by hand isn't fun. Have you thought about using MySQL?

Comment: yes, it would be good to use a table but i am writing only part of an application that fits in with another application.  My side of things is required to be self contained so i cant use a table.  So far the only thing i can come up with is an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of for this situation is an associate array, stored as JSON.

As I don't know where your data is coming from, I'm just going to pretend.

```
$item['price'] = 123;
$item['otherinfo'] = 'stuff';

$data[] = $item;

// repeat for all data. foreach loop over it if you can
```

Then, depending how you want to store the data (rewrite every time, append to the file, etc.. Info at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp) for different ways to open a file):

```
$json = json_encode( $data );
$file = fopen( 'storage.txt', 'w+' ); // opens and clears the file. probably not the best, see link above
fwrite( $file, $json );
fclose( $file );
```

Then, when you want to load the data:

```
$string = file_get_contents( 'storage.txt' );
$data = json_decode( $string );
```

Hope that gets you off to a good start.